# Pandas: Calculate mean, var of similar columns grouped together

Tags: python, pandas, ip

Trying to do a analysis of network trace data using pandas. I have read the dump file and created the following `DataFrame`:
[image: Dataframe]

So to detect the individual flows in the `DataFrame` `data2`, I have grouped the entire `DataFrame` according to `['ip_src', 'ip_dst', 'sport', 'dport', 'ip_proto', 'service']` using the following piece of code:

```
flow = ['ip_src', 'ip_dst', 'sport', 'dport', 'ip_proto', 'service']
grp1 = data2.groupby(flow, sort=False)
```

So when I do `grp1.size()` of the first twenty rows of `data2`, I get the following information:

[image: Grouping]

What I would like to do now is to calculate the `mean` of `ip_len`, `packet_len`, `var` of `ip_len`, `packet_len` and `mean` of the interpacket arrival times (using the `timestamps` of packets belonging to the same flow).

How can I accomplish this in pandas so that the dataframe I get contains the statistics of each flow i.e. the columns should contain the `ip_src`, `ip_dst`, `sport`, `dport`, `ip_proto`, `service`, and the mean & var values calculated as earlier. I have tried both the `aggr` and `apply` methods, but haven't been able to do it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did any of the answers help?

Answer (score 1):

```
data2.groupby(['colName1','colName2']).mean()
```

should do the job.